# DNS resolution fails on android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, dns

There is restriction on UDP response size for DNS protocol. It can only contain ~500bytes. When data exceeds the limit all the DNS servers sets flag "truncated" in response but some (google 8.8.8.8 for example) does not put any IPs in response others just put trimmed list. Utilities like nslookup and dig tries to ask DNS server by TCP to get full response but android does not. Instead it fails. The example of code that fails is bellow.

```
var host = "prdimg.affili.net";
var addressList = Dns.GetHostEntry(host).AddressList;
```

The Modernhttpclient uses gets IPs the same way so I cannot get files from prdimg.affili.net.  To fix it I've implemented the temporary solution. I use GooglePublicDnsClient to resolve DNS and then change hostname to resolved ip with UriBuilder.

`var builder = new UriBuilder(originalUrl);
builder.Host = ip;`

But the solution has two disadvantages

1. it does not work for https because of certificate check
2. it does not work if server uses Vhosts

Can anyone propose a better solution?

Comment: I don't know why, but this question and approach seems over-complicated for such a simple and a trivial thing as DNS. What was really the problem here and wasn't it an other issue than DNS?